# how to open a nc4 file in python3 installed in ubuntu-linux?

Tags: python, linux, import, using, netcdf4

i typed these command on python3 on Ubuntu, i expected to have my file open, but it seems that I have not closed the argument and when I press enter the >>> appears at the next line. What am I missing?

```
import netCDF4 as nc
fn = the path to my file
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)
```

nothing happened!

Comment: `>>>` is the top-level prompt. If you didn't close the argument `...` would appear on the next line.

Comment: Type `ds` to see the value of the variable.